# Do you have a real world example of AttachedPropertyBrowsableWhenAttributePresentAttribute usage?

Tags: wpf, attached-properties

I just come across [AttachedPropertyBrowsableWhenAttributePresentAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.attachedpropertybrowsablewhenattributepresentattribute.aspx), but can't think of when it would be useful.  Any ideals?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Browsable means that a designer, like Visual Studio's WPF designer named Cider, shows the property in the designer. Since attached properties are not an actual property of a type and  can be applied to almost type it is hard for the designer to know when to show or not show the property. These attributes are a way for a developer to let the designer know a certain attached property should be shown in the designer. In other words: Browsable. This specific attribute lets the designer know that this attached property should be browsable on types that have the specified attribute applied to them.

The attached property:

```
public class WhenAttributePresentTestControl : Grid
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ShowWhenCustomAttributePresentProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
      "ShowWhenCustomAttributePresent",
      typeof(int),
      typeof(WhenAttributePresentTestControl));

    public static void SetShowWhenCustomAttributePresent(UIElement element, int value)
    {
        element.SetValue(ShowWhenCustomAttributePresentProperty, value);
    }

    [AttachedPropertyBrowsableWhenAttributePresentAttribute(typeof(MyCustomAttribute))]
    public static int GetShowWhenCustomAttributePresent(UIElement element)
    {
        return (int)element.GetValue(ShowWhenCustomAttributePresentProperty);
    }
}
```

Usage example:

```
[MyCustomAttribute]
public class CustomLabel : Label
{
}

public class CustomLabelNoCustomAttribute : Label
{
}
```

The designer will show the ShowWhenCustomAttributePresent attached property in the property editor for the CustomLabel, but not for CustomLabelNoCustomAttribute.

**Source:** http://blogs.msdn.com/jnak/archive/2008/01/17/showing-attached-properties-in-the-cider-wpf-designer.aspx

**Actual usage:**
I can not find any usage of this attribute in the .Net framework with Reflector.

**Funny side note:** Apparently it is also the [longest type name](http://blogs.msdn.com/mwinkle/archive/2008/05/01/proving-a-point-with-linq-or-the-longest-type-names-in-the-net-framework.aspx) of the .Net 3.0 framework

Comment: Thanks, it just seems odd that it depends on putting an attribute on the target class, when the main point of attached properties is to avoid have to add “stuff” to controls just because they may be used as a child of yours.